# How do I change a "NavigationLink" so it appears onscreen as a button?

Tags: button, uibutton, swiftui-navigationlink

I am currently working on my first "project". I have built an app for work, and although the core concepts are in place (which I'm very proud of!) I'm now trying to make it look a little more "aesthetically pleasing". I am currently using NavigationLinks to navigate through the app, but would like to change these into buttons. How can I do this?

I have of course searched on here but the previous questions/answers that looked similar to my problem have not worked. Here is the first view page:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack { Image("contegologo")
           
        
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2()) {
                    Text("Tap to Begin").foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
         
                }
            }
        
        }
}
```

I just want to change the navigation link into a button! Feels like it should be simple but what I have tried thus far has not worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add a buttonStyle

Comment: hi, could you please elaborate slightly? thanks

Comment: Just type “.buttonStyle” at the end of link at the closing bracket. Depending on the version you support there are many built in styles.